# javascript memory model: access property directly vs using a getter function

Tags: javascript

Say you write an javascript object `service` like this:

```
window.service = (function() {

    var list = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];

    return {
        list: list,

        setList: setList,
        getList: getList
    }

    function setList( l ) {
        list = l;
    }

    function getList() {
        return list;
    }

}());
```

There is two ways to get the value of `list`, and both working very well.

```
// output: ["A", "B", "C"]
console.log( service.list );

// output: ["A", "B", "C"]
console.log( service.getList() );
```

But, when I try to update the `list` value, and access its value again like this:

```
service.setList( [ 1, 2, 3 ] );

// output: ["A", "B", "C"]
console.log( service.list );
// output: [1, 2, 3]
console.log( service.getList() );
```

some strange problem happend, I found `service.list` still print the value `["A", "B", "C"]` after set the new value to `list`.

I was so confused, and do not konw why this happend, does the `chrome browser` cached the value of `list`, does this is a not correct way to assess property? Why? any explanation what I am doing (thinking) wrong?

**Compare with** `java`, the code like this:

```
public class Service {

    public CustomObject obj = new CustomObject("Name A");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service = new Service();
        // output: name:Name A
        System.out.println(service.obj);

        CustomObject updateObj = new CustomObject("Name B");
        // update it
        service.obj = updateObj;
        // output: name: Name B
        System.out.println(updateObj);
    }

}

public class CustomObject {

    private String name;

    public CustomObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("name:" + name);
    }

}
```

In `java`, when you assign a new value to a `reference`, it will get updated correctly, the `reference` will point to the new value automatically. Is this experience where I get from `java` doesn't suitable to `javascript`?

Comment: Doesn't the first piece of code return before it even defines setList and getList?

Comment: It's because you're returning reference to original list.

Comment: @jeoj in javascript declarations are hoisted to the beginning of the function.

Comment: @jcubic In `java`, when you change the filed of another object directly, you will get the correct value after changed, everything working well. So, in `javascript`, I have to give up this experience learn from `java` ? Why `javascript` won't give the correct value `[1, 2, 3]` the `list` referenced?

Comment: Because `service.list` refers to an array in the memory, not to the local variable `list`. Please don't forget, there are no classes nor fields in JavaScript.

Comment: ^^^... + everything is passed by value in JS. In this case, a copy of the reference to the array was assigned to `service.list`. _A reference_, which is a value. This value won't change, unless you explicitely change it.

Comment: The `list` property in your returned `object` is _not the same variable_ as your declared `list`, that key points to your initial array (which is initially stored in `list`). When you change the variable `list`, however, it does not change the object with the key `list`, that still refers to the initial list. So `Object[key] !== key`, actually.